# How do split and patsplit work?

Tags: awk, gawk

1. From Gawk's manual

   > ```
   > patsplit(string, array, fieldpat, seps)
   > ```
   >
   > Divide `string` into pieces defined by `fieldpat` and store the pieces
   >   in `array` and the separator strings in the `seps` array.

   Is it correct that

   - `patsplit` finds the leftmost, longest and nonoverlapping matches to regular expression `fieldpat` in string `string`, and store the
     matches in `array`?
   - The strings in `seps` are created by removing the strings in `array` from `string`?
2. From Gawk's manual

   > ```
   > split(string, array, fieldsep, seps)
   > ```
   >
   > Divide `string` into pieces separated by `fieldsep` and store the
   >   pieces in `array` and the separator strings in the `seps` array.

   Is it correct that

   - `split` finds the leftmost, longest and nonoverlapping matches to regular expression `fieldsep` in string `string`, and store the
     matches in `seps`?
   - The strings in `array` are those created by removing the strings in `seps` from `string`?

Thanks

Comment: Mostly yes, but thinking of "all matches" in terms of arrays is misleading.  All implementations of global matches involve some kind of "cursor" (the `pos()` thing in Perl).  There are various consistency problems otherwise.

Comment: Thanks.  you may find this interesting https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379375/674  which is just one vote  away from reopening.